# How to upload directory to ftp using ftplib?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with upload all files to ftp: I use [ftplib](http://ftplib.codeplex.com/).
I have a function to upload:

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir, FtpConnection ftp)
{
  try
  {
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
      string dirname = new DirectoryInfo(d).Name;
      if (!ftp.DirectoryExists(dirname))
      {
        ftp.CreateDirectory(dirname);
      }
      ftp.SetCurrentDirectory(dirname);
      foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
      {
        Uri uri = new Uri(f);            
        ftp.PutFile(f, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath));

      }
      DirSearch(d, ftp);
    }
  }
  catch (System.Exception e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Błąd FTP: {0} {1}", e.Message), "Błąd wysyłania plików na FTP", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
  }
}
```

ok this function uload files but I have in local disc files:

```
UPLOAD
--DIR1
----DIR3
------FILE4
----FILE3
--DIR2
----DIR4
------FILE7
----FILE5
----FILE6
--FILE1
--FILE2
```

In serwer I have:

```
UPLOAD
--DIR1
----DIR3
------DIR2
--------DIR4
----------FILE7
--------FILE5
--------FILE6
------FILE4
----FILE3
```

I dont have files in first folder and dir tree is wrong
i think foult is in line  ftp.SetCurrentDirectory(dirname);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your function is the problem - when you enter the folder, and copy the files into it, you are not going back to the previous folder, instead you are going more deeply into tree.

Simple solution for this is to rewrite this function to go back from the directory once it has iterated through it:

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir, FtpConnection ftp)
{
  try
  {
     // First, copy all files in the current directory
     foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
     {
       Uri uri = new Uri(f);            
       ftp.PutFile(f, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath));
     }

    // For all directories in the current directory, create directory if there is
    // no such, and call this function recursively to copy files.

    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
      string dirname = new DirectoryInfo(d).Name;
      if (!ftp.DirectoryExists(dirname))
      {
        ftp.CreateDirectory(dirname);
      }
      ftp.SetCurrentDirectory(dirname);
      DirSearch(d, ftp);
    }



  }
  catch (System.Exception e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Błąd FTP: {0} {1}", e.Message), "Błąd wysyłania plików na FTP", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
  }
  finally{
     // Go back! 
     ftp.SetCurrentDirectory(".."); //untested, but it should be fine, as I don't see cdup command in ftplib
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. You can save and assign the current directory on each call. Try this:

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir, FtpConnection ftp, string currentDirectory)
{
  try
  {
    ftp.SetCurrentDirectory(currentDirectory);
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
      string dirname = new DirectoryInfo(d).Name;
      if (!ftp.DirectoryExists(dirname))
      {
        ftp.CreateDirectory(dirname);
      }      
      foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
      {
        Uri uri = new Uri(f);            
        ftp.PutFile(f, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath));

      }
      string newCurrentDir = currentDirectory + dirname + "/";
      DirSearch(d, ftp, newCurrentDir);
    }
  }
  catch (System.Exception e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Błąd FTP: {0} {1}", e.Message), "Błąd wysyłania plików na FTP", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
  }
}
```

and method calling

```
DirSearch("your initial dir", your ftp connection, "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is good

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir, FtpConnection ftp, string currentDirectory)
{
    try
    {
        ftp.SetCurrentDirectory(currentDirectory);
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(f);
            ftp.PutFile(f, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath));

        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            ftp.SetCurrentDirectory(currentDirectory);
            string dirname = new DirectoryInfo(d).Name;
            if (!ftp.DirectoryExists(dirname))
            {
                ftp.CreateDirectory(dirname);
            }

            string newCurrentDir = currentDirectory + "/" + dirname ;
            DirSearch(d, ftp, newCurrentDir);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Błąd FTP: {0} {1}", e.Message), "Błąd wysyłania plików na FTP", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```